# compare single dimensional Array with Multidimensional array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, multidimensional-array, javascript-objects

I am using javascript to compare a single array and a multidimensional array.
Here i want to compare those 2 array and the matched value should be shown.

- `arr[1,2,3]` value to be searched in multidimensional array " md2 ".

This is my Code :: i have taken an single array and other as multidimensional array

```
var arr = [1,2,3];
var md2 = [[23,8,2],[1,5,8],[1,2,3],[8,5,2]];
for(var j=0; j<md2.length ; j++){
  if(arr == md2[j]){
    console.log(arr + " ... " + md2[j]);
  }
}
```

Required O/P :- `[1,2,3]` should match and should be displayed in the console

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to compare arrays in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837456/how-to-compare-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.find()` and `.every()` methods to find array inside multi-dimensional array:

```js
var arr1 = [1,2,3];
var arr2 = [1,2,5];
var md2 = [[23,8,2],[1,5,8],[1,2,3],[8,5,2]];

var searchAndPrint = (a1, a2) => {
  let arr = a1.find(a => a.every((v, i) => v === a2[i]));
  
  if(arr)
    console.log(arr);
  else
    console.log("No Results");
};

searchAndPrint(md2, arr1);
searchAndPrint(md2, arr2);
```

Comment: A shorter solution (but maybe less performant), could be to coerce arrays in string and then compare them, in place of using `every`

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare `arrays` in js. If you wanna compare simple arrays you can convert them to `string` to compare. This method is not applicable to array containing `objects`.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3];
var md2 = [[23,8,2],[1,5,8],[1,2,3],[8,5,2]];
for(var j=0; j<md2.length ; j++){
  if(arr.toString() === md2[j].toString()){
    console.log(arr + " ... " + md2[j]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify` to compare the arrays.

```js
var arr = [1,2,3];
var md2 = [[23,8,2],[1,5,8],[1,2,3],[8,5,2]];
for(var j=0; j<md2.length ; j++){
  if(JSON.stringify(arr) === JSON.stringify(md2[j])){
    console.log(arr + " ... " + md2[j]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For checking, you need to check the length and the items directly, because you have no same object reference.

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3],
    md2 = [[23, 8, 2], [1, 5, 8], [1, 2, 3], [8, 5, 2]];
    
console.log(md2.some(a => arr.length === a.length && a.every((v, i) => v === arr[i])));
```